# Is there any limit for shared memory(shmop) block system id (PHP)

Tags: php

i am creating an app that must check(count) users'(write-intensive) requests.

'shmop_open(MY_INT_USER_ID, ... )' returns a system ID for shared access but i am not sure about this, is there any limitation for shmop system IDs on 64-bit OS? Or does this cause problems, such as collisions?

Comment: Shared memory limits are defined by the operating system.  What are you using here, Linux?

Comment: Yes, i am using x64 Centos 6 dist. with 32gb RAM and AMD Opteron x8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I originally wrote a big post about how to change [shared memory settings in Linux](http://rwitkop.com/VistA/ConfigureSysctl4Cache.html), but then I re-read your question and noticed you were asking about the "system id" passed to [`shmop_open`](http://php.net/shmop_open).

The "system id" is just a 32-bit integer that acts as a key.  There's no magic to it, and the only real limitation is that it's not zero and is under 32 bits.  Yes, this is true even on 64-bit systems running 64-bit PHP.  It's a POSIX thing.

Beware that there's no namespacing or effective security control.  External programs that know about the key are able to access it, assuming that you've set the permissions accordingly.  Shared memory isn't appropriate for use on shared hosting.

Comment: Thanks Charles your post is really helpful. So i think i need memcached now. There is no security problem about storing my data on memory but, unfortunately my user keys must be unsigned big int :S

Comment: Just because they're stored as bigints doesn't mean that they're numerically larger than 32-bits.  I highly doubt that you have 2,147,483,647 user accounts to worry about.  (Keep in mind that PHP integers are signed, which consumes a bit.)

Comment: You are right 32-bit integers enough for using them as shm keys but i am using MySQL too. Naturally, the ID of a record can be greater than  2147483647. To avoid potential problems about this, i'm using BC Math at PHP side(although my system+php is 64-bit) because of the app engine must check/validate every cache(count data) IDs correctly. Think about this; record ID col. has AUTO_INCREMENT feature on database, so user/record IDs can grow quickly, because of there are lots of in/out to database.

Comment: Yeah, but let's think about the number, man.  Two **billion**, one hundred forty seven **million** four hundred eighty three thousand six hundred forty seven users.  You aren't Facebook, you aren't going to need all the space of a MySQL BIGINT to store your user IDs.

Comment: Given that, I think your backup plan of using memcached may work out for you better.  With memcached, you set key lifetimes and a maximum limit on an instance-by-instance basis.  With shared memory, you have to juggle that yourself.